# PHP Dom replace text - Keep case

Tags: php, dom, replace

I am using the below code to replace some text which is working fine. Where the issue lies is that I would like to set some text to search for (i.e `Black`) and rather than just telling it to replace `Black` with `<div>Black</div>` I would like it to be able to look at the case of the word or string and keep that case. At the moment if I tell it to replace `Black` with `<div>Black</div>` it will replace both `Black` and `black` with the uppercase `<div>Black</div>`.

I hope I have made some sense as to what I wish to achieve. If more information is needed let me know.

Here is the code:

```
$revised = str_ireplace("Black", "<div>Black</div>", $node->wholeText);
$newNode  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$newNode->appendXML($revised);
$node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use case-sensitive `str_replace`

```
echo str_replace(array('black', 'Black'), …
```

or use a regular expression

```
echo preg_replace('/(black)/i', '<div>$1</div>', 'Black black');
```